# What are the independence assumptions of Cox models with time varying covariates?

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

In longitudinal studies, you might be observing time-to-event endpoints with some covariate that changes as a function of time. When covariates are fixed at baseline, the only independence assumption involved is within the risk set, or the collective at risk observed during event times. Otherwise, the fact that an individual survived at time 4 is in no way expected to influence whether that individual survived at time 8 (aside from the modeled covariates and baseline hazard).

When individuals have a discrete change in covariates,  they are censored at that time and reintroduced into the analysis at another point. In this case, I expect there should be no reason to handle the fact that individuals were in risk sets at another point in time with different values. The only exception I can conceive of is whether the influence of the covariate has any cumulative effect (but that seems to be a significantly different question, and more of an assumption about the linear model than Cox regression).

Can you confirm that my reasoning is correct?

Comment: I would challenge the proposition that "there should be no reason to handle the fact that individuals were in risk sets at another point in time with different values". If the covariates vary within an individual then there are many other unmeasured features in that individual that do not vary or vary in an individual specific manner. So each individual should form a cluster in the analysis.